# useNewUrlParser : true issue when we have @ in password mongodb nodejs driver 3.1.8

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

As I switched to useNewUrlParser: true, after seeing depreciated waring to use new url parser,  I have landed into connection issues as my password consists of '@'. After doing my research I found that I need encode my URI and pass uri_decode_path: true. But I realized that on '2.2.25 2017-03-17' the support for uri_decode_path is removed. Hence, I dont even have work around now.

Can you please help me understand how to connect to mongodb which has @ in password ?

Comment: URI encoding username and password resolves the issue.